# Gnome - Lock screen - What's this button?

Tags: gnome

In lock screen of Debian or Ubuntu Gnome, I got the following button:

[image]

It looks like a "pause" icon. When I clicked on it , I got a black screen and no way to get back to the work space except of restarting. It seems to similar to a hibernate mode, but from hibernate mode I can restore everything by pressing a key.

Comment: It looks like a bug that you can't unlock the system after you use suspend the system via this button. I disagree that the controls shouldn't be there for “security” reasons: they provide useful quick access to some important yet benign settings that don't compromise the privacy or integrity of a user session or system in practice. (In many cases someone with physical access to the system can change these through external controls not necessarily related to the system in question anyway.) I think you can still disable them through some Dconf or PAM settings.

Comment: I had the same symptom using VirtualBox v5.2.12, but sending ACPI shutdown signal wake it up (and it doesn't shutdown).

Comment: I had the same problem on Ubuntu 18.04. After pressing the pause button, the system goes into hibernation. Before pressing the pause button there was no option to log in. The only trick brings everything back to normal is the single press of power button (don't long press, of course, it will restart the system). I can now see the screen and option to log in.

Comment: If running under VMware you can resume the machine in the VMware GUI.

Answer (score 3):

Sorry, but what it normally does is to hibernate the system.

On my system (Ubuntu GNOME) this works perfectly. It should turn off your monitors after time but let yourself into the system again after one click on a keyboard or mouse button (movement). This looks like an error in your System.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, it was pretty annoying. You need to change the settings in the terminal by:

```
sudo -H gedit /etc/systemd/logind.conf
```

Your current setting is this:

```
HandleLidSwitch=suspend
```

To fix this behaviour, change `suspend` to either `hibernate` or `poweroff`.

Credits: http://tipsonubuntu.com/2018/04/28/change-lid-close-action-ubuntu-18-04-lts/